# SMTP server hacked and Spammed - hotmail.com blacklisted

Tags: iis, smtp, pop3, email

We recently set upp a new SMTP server and during the night someone used it to spamm. Next day We saw that it was over 90 000 mails in the queue folder. After that I chaned the incoming port and also added credentials to the SMTP server. But my ip got blocked from the hotmail.com.  Does someone know how to contact hotmail?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if hotmail keeps its own blacklist, or whether they use public available blacklists, because to get removed from those the process differs on a per-list basis. A small write-up on how to get removed from some lists you can find via [this link](http://searchexchange.techtarget.com/news/1182942/Part-3-How-to-remove-your-Exchange-server-from-spam-blacklists). You should first check where (on what list) your IP is blocked, i.e. on which spam lists your IP is listed as sending SPAM.

A good site which queries multiple blacklists is [blacklist.ie](http://www.blacklist.ie/)

To get removed from hotmail's blacklist you should contact hotmail directly via abuse@hotmail.com. Or even better via the [hotmail support contact form](https://support.msn.com/eform.aspx?productKey=edfsmsbl&ct=eformts). If you need help filling the form, you should look at [this template](http://www.streamsend.com/kb2/idx.php/13/057/Improving-Delivery/article/Answering-the-Sender-Information-for-Hotmail-Delivery-Form-.html).

Usually your IP is white listed automatically after a certain grace period of no spam-related issues, so you might as well wait for this period to be over.

Comment: Iam listed in "Barracuda", do you know How I can remove the listing from Barracuda

Comment: http://www.barracudacentral.org/rbl/removal-request/<your IP here> e.g. http://www.barracudacentral.org/rbl/removal-request/127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

You might have a look at the whois entry. There should be listed contact informations. Besides that, this question might be a better fit on Server Fault.

Comment: should be a comment

Comment: The second part for sure, but the first part (have a look in the whois database) is an answer as well. Though not suited here. Or should this questions be left unanswered and just be commented as "wrong StackExchange site"?